# Best strategy to detect if 2 words are different while uveiling as little as possible

Tags: probability, soft-question, algorithmic-game-theory

I though of the following problem; I did not have time to seriously think about and I probably won't, but rather than forgetting it I thought, *maybe*, someone will like it so I decided to post it here.

Two people have chosen a word in a given list of words $L$. They do not choose the words in order to maximize something: the words are chosen for exogeneous reasons (see Examples below). What is the best strategy to detect if both chosen words are different, while minimizing the information given (so that the other one cannot guess your word)?

For example, let say $L$ is an English dictionary, person P1 chooses "a" and person P2 chooses "question". The strategy could be to give the number of letters, but then it will be easy (in the sense of high probability) for P2 to guess P1's word "a". It could also be the letter of highest rank, i.e. a for P1 and t for P2.

*Edit*  Examples of application:

- two people want to make sure they are not offering each other the exact same product (without revealing what their presents is).
- two people want to make sure their birthdays is not the same month.
- two pregnant sisters want to make sure they are not giving the same first name to their newborn (and want to wait the birth to give out the name).

Comment: Each person uses a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) on their words, say [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), and then they compare hashes.

Comment: But if they both know the complete list of words, they can compute the hash for the entire list, if it is not huge.

Comment: In disclosing the letter of highest rank, "a" also gives away the word.  If they know the lists beforehand, P1 chooses a word with the most frequent length in the list, tells P2 the length, and P2 chooses a word of different length.  Would that work?  I'm not sure I understand the objective of the game...is it to choose different words, or to guess the opponent's word?

Comment: @gariepy There is no "game"; the words are chosen independently (see examples in Edit). The objective is to find a good strategy to make sure the words are different while not revealing them.

Comment: @anderstood: but there has to be an ordering for this problem to make sense.  If not, and the two people have already made their choices simultaneously and independently, then there is a chance they selected the same word/date/name.  In that case, there is no "strategy" to avoid picking the same choice, because the choice is made, and there is no information that can be shared to determine a difference because the choices are not different.

Comment: @gariepy I see, I should have said "detect" rather than "make sure", because indeed the words can be the same---that's precisely the objective of the game, to detect whether there are. Is it more clear now?

Comment: @anderstood: yes, that's better.  I would say a strategy that is "binary search-like".  For words, "is your word in the first half or last half of the list", if both are yes, or both no, subdivide further.  For dates, "is your birthday in the first half of the year or last half of the year".  I don't have a proof, but this seems like it would give away the least amount of information before determining the choices were different.

Comment: There is nothing magic about words.  You can turn whatever list you are using into the numbers $1$ through $n$ and ask whether the numbers are the same.  That gets you out of artificial divisions like number of letters.  You can just pick groups of numbers of whatever size fits your strategy.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes of course. You could code numbers in basis 26 (and I don't see the difference with using letters in this context) or basis 10 but still the number of digit would be a possible criterion (among many).

Comment: It is just the natural divisions between words are letters in them, length, etc.  If you are doing a binary search, you want to divide the possibilities in half.  There may not be an easy split when you think of them as words.  If you think of them as numbers,it is easy.  The words here are just items on a list-you don't care about meaning, part of speech, etc.  I think using numbers helps focus.

Answer (score 2):

I would say a strategy that is "binary search-like". For words, "is your word in the first half or last half of the list", if both are yes, or both no, subdivide further. For dates, "is your birthday in the first half of the year or last half of the year".  Again, if both yes or both no, subdivide further.

I don't have a proof, but this seems like it would give away the least amount of information before determining the choices were different.

Comment: The expected number of bits of information you'd need to pass, assuming both chose  uniformly and randomly and the list is fairly large, would be approximately  $2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So that's a very good strategy. The dichotomy could also be done on a property (e.g. number of letters) but I don't think it changes anything.